# Parse JSONarray in PostgreSQL Query using json_extract_path_text and json_array_elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL query like the following that works and returns foo as expected.

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"}}','f4', 'f6') as foo
```

This does not work.  It just returns null.

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":[{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"},{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"}]}','f4', 'f6') as foo
```

I have tried about every combination of the functions I can find at [PostgreSQL Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) website. Thus my question is, how do I get to the foo in the json array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I did get this to work, but it seems like there has to be a better way:

```
SELECT 
json_extract_path_text(
    json_array_elements(
        cast(json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":[{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"},{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"}]}'::json,'f4') as json
            )
    ),'f6'
) as foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to accomplish something similar that may be useful

```
someJsonColumn::json #>> '{someObj,0,SomeObj,0}' as myJsonField
```